# I need to obtain the complete object to make a notification with firebase

Tags: android, function, firebase

I have this code that works correctly but I want to add the 'mensaje' in the body of the notification, the problem is that I do not know how to get it to be able to send it.

This is the structure of my data in firebase:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqHJu.png)

And this is the function:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
let admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendPush = functions.database.ref('/chats/{chat}/{mensaje}/').onWrite((snapshot, context) => {
 nombreChat = context.params.chat;
    return cargarUsuarios(nombreChat).then(usuarios => {
        let tokens = [];
        for (let user of usuarios){
            if(user.token !== undefined){
                console.log('User', "Usuario: " + user.nombre);
                console.log('User token', "Token: " + user.token);

                tokens.push(user.token);
            }
        }
        let payload = {
            notification:{
                title:'Trado GO',
                body: 'Has recibido un nuevo mensaje',
                sound: 'default',
                badge: '1'
            }
        };
        return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload);

    });

});

function cargarUsuarios(chat){
    var arrayParticipantesChat = chat.split(',');
        let dbRef = admin.database().ref('/usuarios');
        let defer = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            dbRef.once('value', (snap) => {
                let data = snap.val();
                let usuarios = [];
                for (var property in data){
                    usu=data[property];
                    if(arrayParticipantesChat.includes(usu['nombre'])){
                        usuarios.push(data[property]);
                    }
                }
                resolve(usuarios);
            }, (err) => {
                reject(err);
            });
        });
        return defer;
}
```

Comment: tienes q hacer un query a `functions.database.ref('/chats/')` y buscar `nombreChat`... eso te va a traer el objecto donde tienes `mensaje`... si armas un token el codigo te puedo decir mas o menos q hacer

Comment: necesitas tambien almacenar el id del chat en algun lugar para despues hacer el query

Comment: Empece con funcion hace 2 dias y no se como hacer lo que me dices.

De esta forma consigo ver toda la informacion del mensaje pero no se como pasarsela a "cargarUsuarios"

`var ref = admin.database().ref('/chats/'+context.params.chat+'/'+context.params.mensaje+'/');
ref.orderByKey().endAt("elOYo").on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.key);
});`